# Flutter just audio with audio services , how to handle button events

Tags: flutter, just-audio, audio-service

How to handle next audio button pressed event and previous audio button event on flutter just audio with audio services , my audio files is encrypted , i must decrypt audio file before playing

```
mediaItem.add(MediaItem(id: "1", title: item.title!,artUri: Uri.file(PathHelper().pathAudio!+"name.mp3")));
_player.setFilePath(PathHelper().pathAudio!+"name.mp3");
```

Comment: mediaItem.add(MediaItem(id: "1", title: item.title!,artUri: Uri.file(PathHelper().pathAudio!+"name.mp3")));
    _player.setFilePath(PathHelper().pathAudio!+"name.mp3");

when i press next button on notification audio returns beginning

i must handle next button pressed event

Comment: add in question with code formatting to easily recognized

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I will just answer the main question about handling button events (I can't answer about encryption).

To handle button events, override these methods in your audio handler:

- `skipToNext`
- `skipToPrevious`
- `click`

The first two handle next and previous buttons in various places including the notification, while `click` handles button presses on a headset. Since some headsets also also have next/previous buttons, and some headset emulate next/previous by long pressing on the volume buttons, etc., `click` can handle multiple types of events. For this reason, `click` takes a parameter indicating which of the 3 types of events occurred (next, previous or play/pause).

The default implementation of `click` is as follows:

```dart
  Future<void> click([MediaButton button = MediaButton.media]) async {
    switch (button) {
      case MediaButton.media:
        if (playbackState.valueOrNull?.playing == true) {
          await pause();
        } else {
          await play();
        }
        break;
      case MediaButton.next:
        await skipToNext();
        break;
      case MediaButton.previous:
        await skipToPrevious();
        break;
    }
  }
```

(Reference: [API documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/audio_service/latest/audio_service/BaseAudioHandler/click.html))